# Is it possible to use Samba with 2FA

Tags: linux, windows, samba, smb, two-factor-authentication

Do you know of any way on **how to secure samba shares with 2FA** in Linux server for Windows clients?

---

I have set up several windows 10 clients and one linux server. The linux server is reachable via wireguard only. It serves a Nextcloud instance and access to Samba File Shares. 
When a client wants to log in to the samba shares, it has to authenticate by username and password. I would like to add a second factor authentication to that so that a user / client has to authenticate with its username + password and a Yubikey or QRCode or whatever second factor my be usable in conjunction with the samba server.

Comment: Do this answer your question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147746/is-there-windows-2fa-machine-login-for-smb-soho

Comment: thank you but unfortunately it does not suit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use firewall rules on the Samba server to block access.  Before connecting Samba, users could authorize via a web page, using the "second" authentication factor, and then their IP address could be permitted through the firewall, and they could continue with regular Samba login.  Not a smooth and well-integrated approach, but it's a solution that could be implemented on a Linux server.

I just implemented a system that monitors `smbstatus` to restrict users to their statically assigned VPN addresses.  See https://serverfault.com/a/1116288/127791.